# it is possible using the BdG method not to obtain the relation $\Delta(0) = 1.76k_{b}T_{c} $?

Tags: computational-physics, superconductivity, simulations

I'm simulating simple 1D superconductors gap using the BdG method, considering hopping terms just with the nearest neighbors, with periodic boundary conditions, using the following Hamiltonian:
$$H = \sum_{<i,j>} t_{ij} c^{\dagger}_{i}  c_{j} + \sum_{<i, j>} \Delta_{ij}c^{\dagger}_{i} c^{\dagger}_{j} + \sum_{<i, j>} \Delta_{ij} c_{i} c_{j}$$.

The code is based on the BdG method. It means that a self-consistent process is made with the order parameter($\Delta$).

So, we start by guessing a value for Delta and then we diagonalize the hamiltonian matrix and compute a new delta values using $\Delta_{ij} = V\sum_{n} u_{n}(i) v^{*}_{n}(j) tanh(\frac{\beta E_{n}}{2})$, until a convergence criteria is satisfied.

I've built the code on my own and when I do the simualation for 10-sites or similar values I cannot obtain the relationship $\Delta(0) = 1.76k_{b}T_{c}$.

So, it is possible using the BdG method not to obtain the relation $\Delta(0) = 1.76k_{b}T_{c} $? Or am I making some other mstake in the code?

Here is an output figure of te simulation.

Here is the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lFMeHP2UEffeIY-26hbpxdEbigXnkmdM?usp=sharing

[image: DeltaxTemperature]

Comment: It might be beneficial to include a more descriptive take on your work (e.g., what formula are you implementing, what approximations you're making, etc). Standard debugging practice is to test your code against other published results. If you did that, you ought to know very quickly if this is a code error or not. And if you've not done this, then your first order of business is to make the comparison.

Comment: I did it now...But the question is more theoretical primarly.